# Display floating point number in decimal form in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following float point number in Python

```
>>>a = 10 ** -10
>>>print a
1e-10
```

How can I display `.0000000001` instead of `1e-10`?

Comment: You presumably know that 1e-10 is not exactly representable in a `float`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> a = "%0.10f" % (10 ** -10)
>>> a
'0.0000000001'
```

Comment: I think your 9 is meant to be a 10 otherwise they only get 9 0's

Comment: @Twitchykid Yes! But him got a point. That is just a exemple. ;)

Comment: Is there a way to remove trailing zeros? For example if I do `"%0.10f" % (10 ** -2)` it will print `0.0100000000`.

Comment: @Mike I don't think so. `0.0100000000` is not the same than `0.0100000000`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit more readable:

```
a = float("1e-10")
format(a, ".10f")
```

**Output**

'0.0000000001'

Answer (score 1):

Or using `format`

```
>>> a = 10 ** -10
>>> '{a:0.10f}'.format(a=a)
```